# Wordpress css menu replication - menu items and items in dropdowns shifted to the right

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to copy a menu from this wordpress installation http://bit.ly/rrWFMH into some non-wordpress php pages.

I moved the menu code to http://bit.ly/vcUn1s . At first I used the original wordpress CSS file and it worked without problems. However, after stripping that css file down I got working menu, but for some reason menu items and items in dropdowns are shifted to the right. I've been trying to fix it for hours , but still no luck...

Can anyone expert in CSS point me out what is wrong with my css, pretty please? :))

I love you guys!

Comment: Stripping it down appears to have removed something you needed. I usually strip down by commenting out all CSS, then adding it back in until it works. Then I delete the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style declaration of `padding:0;` to your `#access .menu-header ul, div.menu ul` declaration and that should do the trick:

```
#access .menu-header ul, div.menu ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: After declaration of padding:0; menu items shifted to correct position, however dropdowns are now centered instead of aligning to the left like in original.

Comment: The menu items appear centered for me in the original, but you can align them to the left quite easily, just add a style declaration of `text-align:left` to your `#access ul ul a {` declaration and that should fix it.

Comment: I was reffering to the grey background alignment, and not the links, but your text-align:left; fix took care of background, and I like left link alignment better :) Thanks so much, Andres!